# ng-tags-input autocomplete display non query matched result

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

view:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="TagsInputController">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags">
       <auto-complete source="queryTags($query)" min-length="1"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
</div>
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller('TagsInputController',['$scope','$timeout','$http',function($scope,$timeout,$http){
      $scope.tags = [
    { text: 'Tag1' },
    { text: 'Tag2' },
    { text: 'Tag3' }
  ];


  $scope.queryTags=function($query){
    return $http.get('tags.php',{
        params:{
            'tag':$query
        }
    })
  }

}]);
```

php:tags.php

```
<?php
$names=array(
    'palash',
    'kailash',
    'kuldeep'
    );

echo json_encode($names); ?>
```

[image: output]

please see the output that i attached, its showing those tags which does not match the query, i do want only to show which matched

Comment: Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: please read my question again, i added the code

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
$scope.queryTags=function($query){
    return $http.get('tags.php',{
        params:{
            'tag':$query
        }
    })
}
```

Will just return your names from `tags.php` without any filtering being done to it, not on the server an not on the client.
You can use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to filter your array based on `$query`

```
$scope.queryTags=function($query){
    return $http.get('tags.php',{
        params:{
            'tag':$query
        }
    }).then(function(names) {
        var filteredNames = names.filter(function(name) {
            return (name.includes($query);
        });
        return $q.when(filteredNames);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete just returns the output given by the promise. To apply filtering you have to provide the method yourself.